# Pytest - custom output of test results

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, pytest

I want to completely custom tests results output.
In `unittest` I can implement my own test runner by example of `unittest.TextTestRunner`. How can I do the same in `pytest`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in ["Writing plugins" section](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_plugins.html#writing-plugins) of pytest documentation, you'll need to work with `pytest` [hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#hooks):

> `pytest` implements all aspects of configuration, collection, running and reporting by calling well specified hooks of the following plugins:

Also see:

- [py.test code snippets](https://gist.github.com/pfctdayelise/3386951)
- [pycon tutorial session](http://pyvideo.org/video/259/pycon-2010--py-test---rapid-testing-with-minimal-) (it also goes through using hooks)

Comment: Seems like hooks allows to just modify information that will be represented in some standard way, but how to completely redesign results report? For example I want to write it to CSV?

Comment: Yeah, that's not like a simple task to do with `pytest`. Have you considered using [nose](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)?

Comment: Gill, that's certainly possible, as far as I know. For an example, look at Mozilla Web QA's pytest module, which formats reports as HTML. A lot of the logic would be the same as formatting them as CSV (though IMO using standard JUnit XML would be a lot better...) https://github.com/davehunt/pytest-mozwebqa/tree/master/pytest_mozwebqa