# Is there any way to print the pytest parameter names

Tags: python, logging, pytest

Whenever pytest is outputting the tests that it has, it always prints out the parameter values, but never the names of the variables.

For example:

```
PASSED test_create_patient.py::test_create_patient[False-True]
```

What I would like it to output is:

```
PASSED test_create_patient.py::test_create_patient[arg1=False-arg2=True]
```

Is this possible? I have tried various pytest flags like -vvv but nothing seems to work for this. It would be very helpful for debugging purposes.

I've looked into answers like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496751/8903959 but I don't understand them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, you can use the [ids parameter](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/parametrize.html#different-options-for-test-ids) in `pytest.mark.parametrize` to customize the parameter ids. In your case, this is inconvenient. While `ids` allows you to provide a custom function to adapt the output, this function only gets the parameter *value* as argument, not the parameter *name*, so you cannot use it to compose your wanted output. Instead, you would have to provide a list of ids:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("arg1, arg2", [(False, True), (True, False)],
                         ids=["arg1=False-arg2=True",
                              "arg1=True-arg2=False"])
def test_create_patient(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

To avoid this, you can use the hook function [pytest_make_parametrize_id](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html?highlight=pytest_make_parametrize_id#pytest.hookspec.pytest_make_parametrize_id) instead, which gets both the parameter name and the value. You have to put it in a `conftest.py` visible to your test. In your case, you can write:

*conftest.py*

```py
def pytest_make_parametrize_id(config, val, argname):
    return f"{argname}={val}"
```

and you would get the wanted notation for each test.

If you want to have this notation only for verbose output (say, with the option `-vv` or more), you can use `config.option` to check the verbosity and adapt the id accordingly:

*conftest.py*

```py
def pytest_make_parametrize_id(config, val, argname):
    if config.option.verbose >= 2:  # -vv or -vvv
        return f"{argname}={val}"
    return repr(val)  # the default
```

Comment: I'm a bit busy at the moment but will try this out soon, thank you so much!